# Rectangles of the Same Size Aren't Shown the Same!

Tags: graphics

I've written a mathematia code which arranges $n$ unit squares in columns of length $m$ (of course, when $n$ is not divisible to $m$, then the last column is not full). This is the code:

```
n = 60;
m = 1;
l = {};
For[i = 0, i <= n - 1, 
 l = Append[l, 
   Rectangle[{Quotient[i, m], Mod[i, m]}, {Quotient[i, m] + .9, 
     Mod[i, m] + .9}]]; i++]
Graphics[{Red, l}]
```

**Here's my problem:** For a fixed value for $n$ (say, $60$), if you change $m$ then you get squares of smaller or larger sizes, as shown below.  I want all the squares for different $m$'s be of the same size. What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

for $n = 60$ and $m = 1$:

[image]

for $n = 60$ and $m = 13$:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've kept your `For` loop but you should ween yourself off that.

```
n = 60;
m = 1;
unit = 20;
l = {};
For[i = 0, i <= n - 1, 
 l = Append[l, 
   Rectangle[{Quotient[i, m], Mod[i, m]}, {Quotient[i, m] + .9, 
     Mod[i, m] + .9}]]; i++]
Graphics[{Red, l}, ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> {unit*Ceiling[n/m], unit*m}]
```

[image]

```
m=60;n=4;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But what don't you like about the "for"? Do you suggest a better alternative?

Comment: More precisely `Ceiling[n/m] + w - 1` where `w=0.9` is the size of squares.

Comment: e.g. `Rectangle[{Quotient[#, m], Mod[#, m]}, {Quotient[#, m] + .9, 
    Mod[#, m] + .9}] & /@ Range[0, n - 1]` but there are probably several others

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Wow! Your last comment makes it possible to use Manipulate, which makes using the code much easier. Thanks.

Comment: @Behzad there are lots of ways to address this as per other answers -- my answer deals solely with the problem you encountered. I'd recommend learning more about functional programming and study some of the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach

```
n = 60;
m = 13;
Grid[Reverse@Transpose@Partition[ConstantArray["■", n], m, m, 1, ""], 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}, ItemStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

---

Yet another approach

```
ArrayPlot[MapAt[White &, #, {1 ;; -1 - Mod[n, m, 1], -1}] &@
   ConstantArray[Red, {m, Ceiling[n/m]}], Mesh -> True, MeshStyle -> White,
      PixelConstrained -> 10]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Mike Honeychurch has addressed the real issue, `ImageSize`, but for fun here is another way to create the grid of rectangles:

```
Graphics @ {Red, 
 Translate[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {0.9, 0.9}], IntegerDigits[Range[n] - 1, m, 2]]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a relatively nasty way to generate the coordinates of the rectangles, but I figured I'd share it anyway:

Starting with a list of length `n`, [partition](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) it into lists of length `m` putting any excess elements (in case `m` does not divide `n`) in their own shorter list.

```
n = 7; m = 3;
Partition[ConstantArray[1, {n}], m, m, 1, {}]
(* {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1}} *)
```

If we map over this list on the second level we get something quite nice:

```
MapIndexed[
 #2 &, (* #2 because the second argument is the position of the element *)
 Partition[ConstantArray[1, {n}], m, m, 1, {}],
 {2} (* Map on second level *)
]
(*{
   {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}},
   {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}},
   {{3, 1}}} *)
```

Now put this together and make some rectangles:

```
n = 60; m = 13;
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[White], (* Edges to look like padding between rectangles *)
  FaceForm[Red],
  MapIndexed[
    Rectangle[#2, #2 + {1, 1}] &,
    Partition[ConstantArray[1, {n}], m, m, 1, {}],
    {2}]
  }]
```

[image]